# Sending SMS notification for Indian mobile numbers from AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to send sms notifications to my indian number from AWS SNS service. While searching about this on the internet many people have mentioned in their post that SMS service is available only for US based mobile phones.

But while reading the SNS documentation i found India in the supported region.

I created a topic in SNS and created SMS subscription for my mobile number but i didnt get the subscription link.

I don't know whether my understanding is correct. Any thoughts about this ?

i tried sending it through AWS Cli commands and boto3 as well.. I got success code but i didnt get any sms..                                                                        `>>> sns.publish(PhoneNumber = number, Message='example text message' )
{'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '96d0fd74-0657-5dd6-ba6d-adb783076e26', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '96d0fd74-0657-5dd6-ba6d-adb783076e26', 'date': 'Thu, 08 Dec 2016 15:58:08 GMT', 'content-length': '294', 'content-type': 'text/xml'}}, u'MessageId': '2b7ed463-2698-53ff-8b85-84a0a3c8c00f'}`

Thanks in Advance

Comment: TRAI-india has restriction to send sms on DND numbers. You can use any india based sms gateway like SPRING EDGE for confirmation delivery.

Answer (score 1):

I had tried it and it is working for me.
In India, all the telecommunication process should be approved by TRAI, Telecom Regulatory Authority Of India. As per TRAI, we can send promotional SMS between 09:00 AM to 09:00 PM only. For more information please visit https://www.trai.gov.in/.

Answer (score 0):

You can send SMS to India mobile numbers.

Simply add the number as 91xxxxxxxxxx and after couple of seconds start sending messages using the 'Publish to topic' from AWS console or via the API.

There is no confirmation process involved in this

Comment: i tried sending it through AWS Cli commands and boto3 as well.. I got success code but i didnt get any sms..

Comment: Not sure if anything would be different but for the sake of it can you try that from the AWS Console directly. I tried 2 different numbers (idea and Vodafone) and got SMS to both

Answer (score 0):

The SMS Notification option with SNS works worldwide, including India.

Go to SNS Service on AWS Service dashboard, you get the following options on left hand side.

- SNS dashboard
- Topics
- Applications Subscriptions
- Text messaging (SMS)

Click Text Messaging (SMS), and you will get the following options:

- Manage text messaging preferences
- View opted-out phone numbers
- Send a text message (SMS)

To run a test, just use the option **Send a text message (SMS)**
If you do not have any constraints on your user/account you should be able to send a SMS. This is would be a good manual test to do before building an integration pipeline.

The places to look for more information would be:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/introducing-worldwide-sms-messaging/
- https://aws.amazon.com/sns/sms-pricing/
- https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/

Comment: I tried this way but it is not working :( Its not even showing an error

Comment: Ur info is wrong Asia region u cannot see sms option,plz correct ur answer to avaoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for sending SMS in India - Notice **MessageAttributes**.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

module.exports.sendSMS = function sendSMS(req, res) {
  var params = {
    Message: "Your OTP verification code is 3493",
    PhoneNumber: "+" + req.body.phone_number,
    MessageAttributes: {
      "AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType": {
        DataType: "String",
        StringValue: "Transactional",
      },
      "AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID": {
        DataType: "String",
        StringValue: "Horoscope",
      },
    },
  };

  var sns = new AWS.SNS({
    apiVersion: "2010-03-31",
    region: "ap-south-1",
  });
  sns.setSMSAttributes({
    attributes: {
      DefaultSenderID: "Horoscope",
      DefaultSMSType: "Transactional",
    },
  });
  return sns.publish(params).promise();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to select the message type as `Transactional`. `Promotional` might not be allowed by the telecom provider by default.

Answer (score 0):

For sending SMS to an Indian number you would need to register yourself on https://www.vilpower.in/ and then you need to get entityId and templateId for the messages you want to send by getting your messages registered and approved.

You can follow the steps mentioned in the following link - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-senderid-india.html

Once you get the entityId and templateId from https://www.vilpower.in/ you will have to send those ids to the SMS call you make via AWS SDK. Documentation related to templateId and entityId can be found here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-send-sms-india.html

You can find the nodejs code below:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

module.exports.sendSMS = function sendSMS(req, res) {
   var params = {
       Message: "Invoice amount Rs 1 has been generated. Click to view and pay.",
       PhoneNumber: "+" + req.body.phone_number,
       MessageAttributes: {
            "AWS.MM.SMS.TemplateId": {
                 DataType: "String",
                 StringValue: "<templateId>",
            },
            "AWS.MM.SMS.EntityId": {
                 DataType: "String",
                 StringValue: "<entityId>",
            },
        },
   };

   var sns = new AWS.SNS({
         apiVersion: "2010-03-31",
         region: "ap-south-1",
   });
   sns.setSMSAttributes({
         attributes: {
              DefaultSenderID: "<senderId>",
              DefaultSMSType: "Transactional",
         },
   });
   return sns.publish(params).promise();
};
```